# Is it a smell to accumulate things in a parameter returned by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, std

I have the following mapper class:

```
class ObjectMapper {
public:
   std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& getMappingForObject(
          Object* object);

private:
    std::unordered_map<Object*, std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>> m_objMapping;
};
```

Whose implementation is something like this:

```
std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& ObjectMapper::getMappingForObject(
      Object* object) {
    const auto mappingTableIterator = m_objMapping.find(object);
    if (mappingTableIterator == m_objMapping.end()) {
        auto it = m_objMapping.emplace(object,
                                          std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>());
        return it.first->second;
    }
    return mappingTableIterator->second;
}
```

So then the caller can do this:

```
std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& mappingTable =
          objMapper.getMappingForObject(object);
```

And go on and add/remove things in `mappingTable`.

Is this a good pattern in C++? I feel this is using a reference output parameter to pass ownership, which is a smell, but I'm not sure. Is there any alternative that is nicer?

Comment: Your `getMappingForObject` is just `operator[]` for maps...

Comment: You didn't pass any ownership, your `unordered_map` only has a raw pointer. You don't have an output parameter. Whether something is a "code smell" is also highly opinionated.

Comment: What does it mean exactly to ask "Is it a smell?"  Perhaps the title should be less colloquial.

Comment: It’s not ”passing” any ownership, but shared mutable state (which it is) is only rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your function in simpler terms show that it is correct, as long as the caller does not store the result for later use and knows that changing the map will invalidate the reference.  Let's get back to that...

Your original function can be rewritten as:

```
std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t>& ObjectMapper::getMappingForObject(Object* object) 
{
    if (m_objMapping.count(object) == 0)
    {
        // a new object, remove test if nothing special needs to be done.
    }
    return m_objMapping[object];
}
```

As a general rule, you should assume that the ObjectMapper object will outlive the scope of the caller. The reference returned is from our own object data, so there should be no lifetime issues, as long as the caller follows the rules.

If you intend to use the returned map for a lengthy amount of time (more than a couple milliseconds :) **or** are in a multi-threaded application, you will want to work with a copy of the map instead, to minimize the time your data structure is under lock, and to 'transactionalize' any changes to your map data.